# Common practices for backup compression levels

Tags: backup, compression

This question may be a bit "opinion based", but please consider it as looking for authoritative source of information on the use of compression levels.

I have a server with few databases with different sizes (from megabytes to 40GB). At this moment we are using `gzip -9` compression level and backups are slow.

We have daily backup policy and we keep:

- daily backups for 14 days
- weekly backups for 2 months
- monthly backups for 2 years
- yearly backups forever

Database backups are done like this: `mysqldump ... > | gzip -9 -c > $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz`

I have tried different compression levels for one of small databases. Here are the results (server was a bit loaded, so it may be a bit inaccurate):

```
level | time (real) | output file size
    1 |    0m1.844s | 6.6M
    3 |    0m1.902s | 6.1M
    5 |    0m2.112s | 5.1M
    7 |    0m2.447s | 4.9M
    9 |    0m3.498s | 4.8M
```

After this I think that 5 or 7 compression level should be used and we should avoid 9 compression level.

The question is:

What are the common practices regarding the compression level for backups?

Are there any standards used in corporations or institutions?

Comment: How often do you make backups? If it's once a day, then 4 minutes (or even 15 minutes) doesn't sound too bad. There are no standards or common practices for this. Some would probably dump to SQL and compress, others would rely on the snapshotting capabilities of the underlying filesystem, and backup filesystem snapshots. Others still might rely on service redundancy rather than backups for disaster recovery.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have added more information. Generally we are trying to keep it simple as possible, so we stop services that may change data during backup, do backup, start services. Service redundancy at this moment is not an option (not enough man power to implement and maintain such system).

Comment: Of course there just cannot be any standard or common practice since… every one has got different size/time to complete demands and cpu time availability. AND, consequently the scheduling model used. (I personally launch my compression utilities SCHED_BATCH so…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the common practices regarding the compression level for backups?

None, everything strictly depends on your needs and abilities.

> Are there any standards used in corporations or institutions?

None, use whatever works for you.

I'd strongly suggest using ZSTD instead of gzip. It's mature enough, much better than gzip in terms of compression ratio and is blazingly fast for decompression. It has 22 compression levels including `--long` and `--ultra`, so you'll need to experiment to find out what works best for you.

Do consider using PAR2 for your compressed data and keep checksums of the original data and compressed data. Without checksums it's easy to lose your data due to bit errors while storing or retrieving data.